# create a batch file loop and restart dependent on user input

Tags: mysql, batch-file

This is my first batch file and I've been having trouble finding answers (or clues which I can decipher). New to programming, and trying to run multiple .sql statements in a single batch file. This I can do. Problem is, the flie only handles one stock @ a time, and the bottom 2 COUNTS files repeat themselves -- so I need to have them run AFTER the user has changed the stock symbol in the first .sql files and have them loop and run until the last stock is input -- then run the COUNTS files at the end.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good  scripts\load_csv_data_MySQL.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_DAILY.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_MONTHLY.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_DEFAULT_updates.sql"

:this is where I need to have the file either loop back through the above scripts with 
:a different stock (with files above updated by the batch user who has access to the  .sql files) or when
:all stocks have been entered, to continue to the 2 .sql scripts below

mysql -h  -uroot -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\INSERT_INTO_COUNTS_daily.sql"
mysql -h  -uroot -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\INSERT_INTO_COUNTS_monthly.sql"
exit
```

Would really appreciate any assistance (keeping in mind my utter lack of experience w/ batch files)!  P.S. This is a personal assignment and not for any type of school, I'm self
teaching using only the net as of now (and Murach's MySQL book)...

Thanks!

Comment: To use user input you'll need to use the `choice` or `set /p` commands. Type `choice /?` or `set /p` for more info. To change the files targeted you'll have to use a buncf of variables and `if` statements. Remember, type `help` to look at all cmd commands and type a command followed by `/?` for info on that command

Comment: So this may be more complicated than I thought. The .sql files themselves will be the same in regards to the batch file (won't "change", just updated with a new stock symbol within the .sql itself). Does that make any difference, or am I still going to have to figure out the commands w/ multiple variables, etc? Thanks for the reply and advice, Monacraft!

Comment: Depends on HOW you want to specify the stocks. You don't appear to be supplying the stock name to your `mysql` instructions. Do you want to get the stock name from a file, or from the keyboard? BTW - your first `mysql` line may fail as it has two spaces btween 'good' and 'scripts' whereas the others have only one...

Comment: That's a typo here, sorry. The stock symbol comes from the person running the batch, who also has access to the .sql files. So, it's coming from the keyboard, but into the .sql files to be re-run. Thanks Peter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the `mysql` commands are not going to change this will work fine:

#### Code :

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
:start
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good  scripts\load_csv_data_MySQL.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_DAILY.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_MONTHLY.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_DEFAULT_updates.sql"
choice /m "Restart Operation ?"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :start
mysql -h  -uroot -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\INSERT_INTO_COUNTS_daily.sql"
mysql -h  -uroot -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\INSERT_INTO_COUNTS_monthly.sql"
exit
```

If not, I can't help since I'm not familiar with it myself

Hope this helped.

Comment: Pretty sure that's good, is that to get a yes/no answer (meaning I can adjust it to say something like "Do you have another stock to enter after this one?")? If so, then thanks so much!

Comment: replace `choice /m "Restart Operation ?"` with `choice /c [options as in "y" or "n"] /m "Text to display"`. If you keep it the same it will ask for either "y" or "n" where "y" will repeat the code and "n" will continue on.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
:again
set "stock="
set /p stock="enter stock symbol "
if not defined stock goto final
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good  scripts\load_csv_data_MySQL.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_DAILY.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\derived_MONTHLY.sql"
mysql -h  -u -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment\1\good scripts\derived_DEFAULT_updates.sql"

goto again

:final

mysql -h  -uroot -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\INSERT_INTO_COUNTS_daily.sql"
mysql -h  -uroot -p -Dstock_market < "C:\mysql assignment 1\good scripts\INSERT_INTO_COUNTS_monthly.sql"
exit
```

This should get you started - will accept stock symbols; pressing just <kbd>Enter</kbd> should run the final two and exit.

**BUT** I gather the entered stock must be used to modify the 4 scripts in the loop. That's a completely different task. Not impossible, but does add to the complexity. You should be able to have your `.sql` script accept a parameter (I'm no expert on `.sql` scripts, so I've no idea precisely how) OR simply rebuild the `.sql` from a template, replacing a key string...

Comment: Thanks for the help, Peter. This is my first attempt at a fully functional DB and realize the .sql is probably non-optimal as I'm learning on the fly. However, that's where the symbols go for now. I appreciate the time and advice a lot.